# How do I detect collision with C++, OpenGL, and freeglut?

Tags: c++, opengl, collision, freeglut

I am making a maze game, and I know how to do everything except make it so that you can't just cheat your way through the walls. I am using freeglut with OpenGL in C++ and I would like to know the most effective way of using collision detection ( hopefully without needing to use anything other than freeglut).

Comment: Personally, I use [Bullet Physics](http://www.bulletphysics.org) to handle all my collision detection.  But for a simple maze game, you can do collision yourself with algorithms like [these](http://www.miguelcasillas.com/?mcportfolio=collision-detection-c).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenGL is just for drawing; it makes things appear onscreen at the coordinates you specify, but it doesn't play a role in deciding what the coordinates of your objects should be.  For motion and collision, you may want to use a physics library, such as [ODE](http://www.ode.org/) or [Bullet](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/).  (There are also bigger, more commercially-oriented physics systems like [Havok](http://www.havok.com/products/physics) and [PhysX](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/physx), but those are probably overkill for a simple project.)

Comment: So of the physics engines you mentioned, which one do you think would go best with what I am doing/ best overall? By the way, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Bullet seems to be popular for games, but I haven't personally used any of these libraries and I don't know anything about your maze game, so I can't really make an informed recommendation.

Comment: To be honest I don't know much about my maze game, it will be my first using graphics, but I just planned to have it scroll using basic viewport functions and using WASD keys to move the camera with an object following it. Which one do you think is the simplest? Sorry if I'm being high maintenance.

Comment: I'd probably start without a physics library, and just do my own checking for whether the player's bounding box is about to intersect a wall.  If that proves inadequate, read through the docs for Bullet or ODE to get a sense of how it'd fit into your program, and if there's something you don't understand, come back to SO with a more-specific question.